# How to redirect URL with wilcard parameters using htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, param

I'm using [Newsletter plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/newsletter) for WordPress. I've sent a newsletter out to my mailing list with a link but the link is not working.
It's creating a url with 
`/?nltr=MTs0NjtodHRwOi8vd3d3LmhlYWx0aHlmb29kc29sdXRpb25zLmNvLnVrL3JlY2lwZS1zdXJ2ZXkvOzsxYWE2NTRhYmQyNjhkZDk4OGZkN2NjNGRiMjhmZjE4MQ%3D%3D`and returing a 404 and not loading the page.
I've logged a support ticket.

I thought I could maybe use `htaccess` to do a wilcard redirect something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?nltr=(.*)  /correct-page/
```

But this doesn't work.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I've turned off tracking as a workaround and the links work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match on `%{QUERY_STRING}`.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383730/1714).