# How to remove a query string from a url?

Tags: regex, linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this:

```
http://www.example.com/pt/?id=114
```

...and I need redirect it to this:

```
http://www.example.com/pt
```

My current code that is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/pt$ /pt [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Any helps?

Comment: Check the `%{QUERY_STRING}` with `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess RewriteRule page with query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383669/htaccess-rewriterule-page-with-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the querystring, you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/?pt$ /pt? [L,R=301,L]
```