# .htaccess RewriteRule between two addresses with hashes

Tags: .htaccess

I have issue with RewriteRule in .htaccess. It works if I do this:

```
RewriteRule example1.com/test example2.com/test1#tab1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

But when I try to use hash in first URL it doesn't:

```
RewriteRule example1.com/test#tab0 example2.com/test1#tab1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem you are experiencing

Comment: So if I left # in first URL it redirect wrong, for example
```RewriteRule example1.com/test#tab0 example2.com/test1#tab1 [L,NE,R=301] ```
it take me from here ``` example1.com/test#tab0 ```  to ```example2.com/test1``` ignoring ```#tab1```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match [fragments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in .htaccess. The fragment is never sent to the server.

You can match `example2.com/test1?tab0`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383730/3150271