# htaccess with hash notpossible

Tags: .htaccess, hash

I want to achieve a redirect via htaccess. Whatever I try, it won't work. I already found out that htaccess is not very fond at hashes. If the url  is:

> https://www.my_url.com/#/page/45

it needs to redirect to:

> https://www.my_url.com/wp-content/plugins/multi/#/page/45

The number at the end can be different. Also very important, this may only kick in when the url is  www.my_url.com/#/. Something there is an path before the hash, and in that case there must be no redirect. Is this even possible, or a lost case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to match fragments in .htaccess. The fragment is never sent to the server.

You can match `https://www.my_url.com/?/page/45`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383730/3150271