# Redirecting a Domain with a Get Variable to a New Domain with the htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to send /bn/referral.php?id=xxxxx to https://www.newdomain.com/index.php?referral=xxxxx

I have it currently set up like this, with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^/bn/referral.php?id=([0-9]+)$ https://www.newdomain.com/index.php?referral=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance for any insight to this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess RewriteRule page with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383669/htaccess-rewriterule-page-with-query-string)

Comment: I would just have the URLs be `/bn/referral/xxxxx` though, easier to type and to rewrite.

Comment: That sounds like more work, no? Rewrite the URL to then Rewrite the URL? Do you have a solution to the question?

Comment: `/bn/referral.php?id=xxxxx` is already being written from a DB, no? You'd just change the construction of it then it is the same. See linked dup for how to resolve the current question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts please try following .htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also I am using here `THE_REQUEST` variable to handle both uri and query string together.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/bn/(referral)\.php\?id=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com/index.php?%1=%2 [R=301,L]
```